# Check if player is not in the air or on a specific block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft 1.14.4, I was wondering if it was possible to use a command block to execute if a player is neither on a specified type of block or in the air.

For instance:

```
/execute if entity @p ~ ~-1 ~ (is not grass or air) run ...
```

If you need clarification on my question feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

`/execute if entity` is for checking for entities. `/execute if block` is for checking for blocks. So you want `/execute at @a unless block ~ ~-1 ~ air unless block ~ ~-1 ~ grass …`.